# python manage.py runserver answer Python

Tags: python, django

```
PS C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mysite\mysite> python manage.py runserver

Python 

PS C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mysite\mysite>
```

When I write a request "python manage.py runserver", I get "Python".

- `Terminal Pycharm`
- `Windows 10`
- `Python 3.10`
- `Django 4.0.3`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually couldn't understand question but I guess you are working with Django, did you activate environment before running "python manage.py runserver"?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to active the virtual environment, its easier if you do everything in the command line.
After activating the environment you can run your command manage.py runserver , but dont forget to put an IP and port, example:

```
    manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```